# Google Maps - Custom Marker Icon appears under the default icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I would like to add a marker with a custom icon on the map.

```
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: coords,
   map: map
 });        
if(attrs.icon)
    marker.setIcon(attrs.icon);
```

Doing this will add a new marker on the map, but it adds the custom icon under the default icon (red location symbol). This is strange. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, you would add a custom icon using the following:

```
  var image = 'http://i.imgur.com/OG4CZt3.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
```

---

Here is the full snippet, [from the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple)

```css
#map {
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
// This example adds a marker to indicate the position of Bondi Beach in Sydney,
// Australia.
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151}
  });

  var image = 'http://i.imgur.com/OG4CZt3.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
</script>
<script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Doing it this way should prevent the custom icon from appearing beneath the default.